# XMLHttpRequest does not working sometimes

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I've created a `ClickListener` which is supposed to make a `POST` request to my server. Most of the times, the POST request is made but sometimes, it fails to make a `POST` request no matter how many times I try. Can anyone help me understand what the issue is and how to resolve it? This is my code where I'm handling that:

```js
$("#Button11").on("click", function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/addtolist", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader(
    "Content-type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "*"
  );
  var parameter = "dc=deal1";
  xhr.send(parameter);
  window.location.href = "/final_page.ejs";
});
```

Comment: The browser may cache the call. Add different parameter to prevent.

Comment: How do I prevent that?

Comment: Add different parameter. Like a random string or timestamp.

Comment: This is NOT a good idea: `xhr.send(parameter);
  window.location.href = "/final_page.ejs";` since your location change can kill the xmlhttp request

Comment: You have a race condition. Send vs window.location Two actions firing at same time

Comment: @MarkusZeller POST does not cache

Comment: @epascarello What, if the browser may block sending the same request? Isn't it some caching like seeing the list in the developer toolbar? But I agree the race condition will surely cause that behaviour.

Comment: @MarkusZeller If POST is blocked b cache, the internet would be broken.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you for clarification. Makes total sense, when I think over. So PUT and DELETE also must be cacheless, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

## The issue

`XMLHttpRequest.send()` is an asynchronous method, that mean this method only ask the request to be sent but it will not be done instantly. Most of the time, this does not matters, but in your script, you redirect the user right after it, so, sometime, the user is redirected before the request is sent.

## The solution

You have to wait the request to be done before redirecting the user, thankfully, `XMLHttpRequest` have a method to achieve it. It is the `XMLHttpRequest.onload()` method. So you can update your script to :

```js
$("#Button11").on("click", function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/addtolist", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader(
    "Content-type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "*"
  );
  var parameter = "dc=deal1";
  xhr.send(parameter);
  xhr.onload = function(){
    window.location.href = "/final_page.ejs";
  };
});
```

As mentioned in the comments, JQuery also have an integrated solution for making request, I recommend you reading it's [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to have an even better solution.

Comment: As I already commented. Also no need for xmlhttprequest at all when you have jQuery

Comment: @mplungjan No need to have jQuery when you have Core JavaScript. lol

Comment: No need to NOT have jQuery when jQuery is already loaded

Comment: I'll definitely give it a read. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @HashimJaved Did this solution work for you?

Answer (score -1):

Your location change is killing your Ajax before it finishes

Also why not use the much simpler $.post now you have it?

None of your headers are needed and the auth header is not even allowed to be set by you

```js
$("#Button11").on("click", function() {
  $.post("/addtolist",{"dc":"deal1"},function() {
    window.location.href = "/final_page.ejs";
  })  
});
```

Comment: I'll try that and let you know. Thank you so much!